# Implementing a fast parallel Matrix Inversion algorithm by cuda but something is not working

Tags: matrix, cuda

Currently, I am implementing
[image: this matrix inversion algorithm here]

for lower triangular matrices by cuda. I am now using only one thread to do the matrix multiplication in the bottom left corner of the matrix. However, it seems that there are some issues with the temporary matrix I used in the code. I suspect that there are some issues on line 24 that the temp matrix cannot store the value after the matrix multiplication. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga1Jq.png). Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

```
void print_mat(int size_small,int size_large, float*m){
    for (int row = 0; row < size_small; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<size_small;col++){
            printf("%.2f ",m[ col + row*size_large]);

            if (col % size_small == size_small-1)
                printf("\n");

        }
    }
}


__device__ void SMM(float *A1inv, float *A2, float *A3inv, float*temp, float * O,int small_size, int large_size){

    for (int i = 0; i  < small_size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j  < small_size; j++){
            temp[small_size*i + j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < small_size; k++){
                temp[small_size*i + j] += A3inv[i*large_size+k]*A2[k*small_size+j];
            }
            temp[small_size*i+j] = -temp[small_size*i+j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i  < small_size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j  < small_size; j++){
            O[large_size*i + j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < small_size; k++){
                O[large_size*i + j] += temp[i*small_size+k]*A1inv[k*large_size+j];
            }
        }
    }

}


__global__ void mat_inv(float*A,float*O,float* temp,int n){

    int ix = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; // global thread ix

    if(ix < n* n){

        // Step 1: copy the element on diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            O[ix*(n+1)] = 1/A[ix*(n+1)];
        __syncthreads();
        // Generate n-series
        int k = n;

        int n_series = 0;

        while (k>0){

            k = k /2;

            n_series++;

        }


        for(int i = 0;i<(n_series-1);i++){
            int m_size = 1<<(i);//size_subm[i];
            int x_start = 0;
            int y_start = m_size;
            int jump = 2*m_size;

            // for each matrix
            int j = ix;

            float *A21 = &A[(x_start + j*jump) +  (y_start + j*jump)*n ];
            float *O21 = &O[(x_start + j*jump) +  (y_start + j*jump)*n];
            float *O11 = O21 - m_size*n;
            float *O22 = O21 + m_size;
            //      if(i ==1)
            //              print_mat_d(n,n,ix,A);

            SMM(O11,A21,O22,temp,O21,m_size,n);

            __syncthreads();


        }


    }
}






int main(){

    int n = 8;

    // Use only 1 block

    int num_blocks = 1;

    // Create a matrix

    float* hA = (float*) malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    float* hO = (float*) malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
    float* dA;
    float* dO;
    float* temp;

    cudaMalloc(&dA,n*n*sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc(&dO,n*n*sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc(&temp,n*n*sizeof(float));




    for(int i = 0; i<n*n;i++){

        if(i%n>i/n)
            hA[i] = 0;
        else
            hA[i] = 1.1;

    }
    print_mat(n,n,hA);

    cudaMemcpy(dA,hA,n*n*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int num_thread_per_block = n;

    mat_inv<<<num_blocks,num_thread_per_block>>>(dA,dO,temp,n);

    cudaMemcpy(hO,dO,n*n*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n");
    print_mat(n,n,hO);



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't see how the code you have written is mathematically the same as the image you referred to. I don't see any submatrix inversion any where in that code. And what do you think that `O[ix*(n+1)] = 1/A[ix*(n+1)];` is doing?

Comment: This is inverting the 1x1 matrix to start with

Comment: But that is mathematically impossible. If the any of those block matrices are 1 x 1, then the others are, by definition, not square and not invertible for anything other than a 2x2 matrix decomposed into 1x1 blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few initial remarks:

- if you're interested in a "fast, parallel" matrix inverse, you should probably just use a [library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html).
- I'm going to assume a matrix side dimension of a power of 2.
- I'm simply going to try and address some deficiencies in your code, without trying to create something "optimal".  I think rather than polishing this, I would prefer to use a library.
- I would not always [assume](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) that inverting a matrix is necessary.

The general approach you have sketched out seems plausible to me for matrix side dimension power-of-2:

- Replace the main diagonal element-by-element with reciprocals.
- Working along "successive subdiagonal directions", use increasing size matrix-multiply operations to fill in the lower triangular result.

As a general statement, it's not clear to me you really understand the thread-parallel nature of CUDA development.  An example of this I see is here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        O[ix*(n+1)] = 1/A[ix*(n+1)];
```

Let's study that.  First of all, the loop on `i` is puzzling to me because `i` is used nowhere in the body of the loop (and the output is disjoint from the input). What purpose does the loop serve?  The body functionality is loop-invariant.  Second, let's consider your indexing.  You have threads whose `ix` variable takes on values ranging from 0 to `n*n-1` if we trust the previous `if` statement. That can't be right.  Of course you are only launching `n` threads here, so it works.  But the loop is unnecessary.

Also note that `__syncthreads()` is illegal inside conditional code, unless all threads can reach it.  So as long as we are not launching more than `n` threads (and we modify the initial `if` statement) we should be OK.

Because you have chosen to have the matrix-matrix multiplications be performed by a single thread in each case, there is never a situation in which we need all `n` threads performing a matrix-matrix multiply, as we progress through the "subdiagonals" (the largest number we will need is `n/2`, at the first "subdiagonal").  Therefore you must be doing too many matrix multiplies, because nowhere do you condition your code to do fewer and fewer matrix multiplies, as you proceed through the subdiagonals, to do the work.  So you must be doing illegal indexing, and this is evident if you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` or `compute-sanitizer`, as I always recommend any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code.  Stated another way, the matrix multiplications needing to be done at each iteration of the second `i` loop is not `n`.  But that is what your code is attempting to do.

Another thing I noticed is that you are not handling `temp` correctly.  All threads are using the same `temp` array with an effective start of 0.  `temp` is not offset correctly, per-thread, so that each thread uses a separate area.

There may be other issues as well.  Due to at least 2 of the above issues, major rewrites would be necessary.  Therefore I've presented my own code, without trying to match yours exactly:

```
$ cat t12.cu
#include <cstdio>
// matrix-matrix multiply, with optional negation, allowing output to overwrite input
template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
void mm(T *A, T *B, T *D,  int stride, int n, bool negate){

  T *C = new T[n*n];  // avoids temp indexing madness
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      C[i*n+j] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)  C[i*n+j] += A[i*stride+k]*B[k*stride+j];}
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) D[i*stride+j] = (negate)?(-C[i*n+j]):(C[i*n+j]);
  delete[] C;
}

// assumes one block only, n == threads per block, n power of 2
// lower triangular matrix invert
template <typename T>
__global__
void ltmi(T *A, int n){
  int i = threadIdx.x;
    // "invert" main diagonal
  A[i*(n+1)] = 1/A[i*(n+1)];

// process "subdiagonals" in order
  int mask = 1;
  for (int s = 1; s < n; s *= 2){
    __syncthreads();
    if (!(i & mask)){ // select needed threads at each "subdiagonal"
      T *mA = A + i*(n+1); // pointer to thread's A sub matrix
      mm(mA+s*(n+1), mA+s*n, mA+s*n, n, s, true); // -A3i*A2
      mm(mA+s*n, mA, mA+s*n, n, s, false);       // A2*A1i
      mask = 2*mask+1;}
    }
}


typedef float mt;
const int n = 8;  // must be power-of-2, 1024 or less
int main(){
// setup matrix
  mt *A;
  cudaMallocManaged(&A, sizeof(*A)*n*n);
  memset(A, 0, sizeof(*A)*n*n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
      A[i*n+j] = 1.1f;

  ltmi<<<1,n>>>(A, n);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      printf("%.6f ",  A[i*n+j]);
    printf("\n");}
}
$ nvcc -o t12 t12.cu -lineinfo
$ compute-sanitizer ./t12
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0.909091 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
-0.909091 0.909091 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
-0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.909091 0.909091
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I have not tested this thoroughly. I don't really recommend this approach.

Comment: I am new to Cuda... Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Your comment and code are definitely very helpful for me to learn cuda. Really opened my mind. Thanks again!